# Google maps V3 ignoring center value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have created a google map with a few markers on it. One of the markers is different to the others though, and I would like this marker to sit in the center of the map. WHen I am building the map I am setting the center of it to the same location as this marker, however it seems to be getting ignored. Here is my code:

```
var map; // Global declaration of the map
        var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); // Global declaration of the infowindow
        var lat_longs = new Array();
        var markers = new Array();
        var markerCluster;
        function initialize() {

            centerlat = '53.1957381200000';
            centerlong = '-2.8940324870000';

            if(centerlat=='FALSE' && centerlong=='FALSE') {
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.4734,-0.137329);
            } else {
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.1957381200000,-2.8940324870000);
            }
            var myOptions = {
                //zoom: 13,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);



            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.6274684, -1.1290035);

            var markerOptions = {
                map: map,
                position: myLatlng,
                title: "Head Office"        
            };
            marker_0 = createMarker(markerOptions);

            marker_0.set("content", '<h4>Head Office</h4><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque quis urna nibh, sed venenatis felis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed suscipit lobortis luctus. Quisque vestibulum facilisis risus, in suscipit nisl hendrerit et.</p><p><a href="#contact_form" class="btn btn-primary contact-office" data-office_id="13">Contact This Office</a></p>');

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker_0, "click", function(event) {
                iw.setContent(this.get("content"));
                iw.open(map, this);

            });



            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.489827, -0.196938);

            var markerOptions = {
                map: map,
                position: myLatlng,
                title: "London"     
            };
            marker_1 = createMarker(markerOptions);

            marker_1.set("content", '<h4>London</h4><p>Our London office is based at the Earls Court Exhibition centre. Our central location allows us to offer our award winning services to all venues across the capital.</p><p><a href="#contact_form" class="btn btn-primary contact-office" data-office_id="12">Contact This Office</a></p>');

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker_1, "click", function(event) {
                iw.setContent(this.get("content"));
                iw.open(map, this);

            });



        /* IF the user has performed a search then add a marker showing the center of the search */
        if(centerlat!=='FALSE' && centerlong!=='FALSE') 
        {
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(centerlat, centerlong);

            var markerOptions = {
                map: map,
                position: myLatlng,
                title: "Your Location",
                icon : "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png"
            };
            marker_you = createMarker(markerOptions);

            marker_you.set("content", '<h4>Your Location</h4><p>This is the approximate location of your search</p>');

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker_you, "click", function(event) {
                iw.setContent(this.get("content"));
                iw.open(map, this);

            });
        }


        var clusterOptions = {
            gridSize: 60,
            minimumClusterSize: 5
        };
        markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clusterOptions);

        fitMapToBounds();


        }


    function createMarker(markerOptions) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
        markers.push(marker);
        lat_longs.push(marker.getPosition());
        return marker;
    }

    function fitMapToBounds() {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        if (lat_longs.length>0) {
            for (var i=0; i<lat_longs.length; i++) {bounds.extend(lat_longs[i]);}
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    }

    window.onload = initialize;
```

Comment: Hi, need a better definition of what you exactly want to happen, and what is currently occurring.  Also, make sure you have deleted your internet files and done a full refresh to ensure you have the latest script files and css on your testing pages.

Comment: it's not ignored, you change the bounds of the map in `fitMapToBounds()` , changing the bounds will also change the center.

Comment: I do not used `fitMapToBounds()` but have the same issue. Without markers the map centers correctly.